# Adding the repository to construct gives user deprecated error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have following lines of code in my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\TaskListRepository;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;

class ListController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @var TaskListRepository
     */
    private $taskListRepository;

    public function __construct(TaskListRepository $taskListRepository)
    {
        $this->taskListRepository = $taskListRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/lists", name="lists")
     */
    public function getListsAction()
    {
        return $this->taskListRepository->findAll();
    }

}
```

When I try to debug route, I am getting following error:

> [info] User Deprecated: Using the WebserverBundle is deprecated since
>   Symfony 4.4. The new Symfony local server has more features, you can
>   use it instead. 2019-12-16T04:37:53+01:00 [info] User Deprecated:
>   Loading the file "../../src/Controller/" from the global resource
>   directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony_rest\src" is depre cated since
>   Symfony 4.4 and will be removed in 5.0.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try to remove `WebserverBundle` ?

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation message that you get has nothing to do with your controller and is just a warning, not an error.

You have included the WebserverBundle bundle in your project, but this bundle will be deprecated past Symfony 4.4. The bundle itself is fine and you can still use it, but it simply means that you won't be able to use it anymore once you move to Symfony 5.

If you don't use the bundle and want to get rid of the deprecation message, simply run the following command:

```
composer remove symfony/web-server-bundle
```